# Handling database close/reopen when using dependency injection with Hilt

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-room, dagger-hilt

In my application database files from Room are uploaded for backup and loaded again when the user signs in. Such a workflow could happen without recreating the activity or restarting the app, meaning singletons provided by Hilt remain. By singletons I mean:

```
@Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideDatabase(@ApplicationContext appContext: Context) =
         MyDatabase.getInstance(appContext)
```

This is injected into a data access object, then repository `MyRepository`, which is injected in the view model:

```
@HiltViewModel
class SignInViewModel @Inject constructor(
    application: Application,
    private val myRepository: MyRepository,
) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
```

This leads to a problem in the workflow:

1. Sign out, clearing database.
2. Go to the sign in screen where the database instance is still used, i.e. injected using Hilt (potentially needed when registering).
3. Load backup but beforehand closing the database with `myDatabase.close()` in `SignInViewModel` before navigating to main screen:

   ```
   myDatabase.close()
   overwriteDatabaseFile()
   ```
4. Navigate to main screen where database operations can be performed and `MyRepository` is also used.

Since the Hilt instance for this database remains the same (being a singleton), this leads to following error when performing any kind of operations on database:

```
(1) no such table: room_table_modification_log in "SELECT * FROM room_table_modification_log WHERE invalidated = 1;"
E  Cannot run invalidation tracker. Is the db closed?
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: room_table_modification_log (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM room_table_modification_log WHERE invalidated = 1;
```

Apparently the old instance thinks the database is still closed. Potential approaches to resolve this:

- Brute force app restart, killing all singleton instances of the database injected using Hilt.
- Don't use Hilt singletons for this database.

Both approaches seem inelegant. Is there a way to handle Room database close and reopen calls without restarting the application or using custom dependency injection?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a custom component:
[How to use Provider<T> from Dagger in Hilt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74790597/how-to-use-providert-from-dagger-in-hilt).

Another option, I would suggest not to make it a singleton, create your own MyDatabaseProvider (static and you can manage it yourself). And instead of passing a specific instance to Repository - pass Provider and don't save this instance anywhere.

```
@Provides
fun provideDatabase(@ApplicationContext appContext: Context) =
    MyDatabaseProvider.get(appContext)

object MyDatabaseProvider{
     private val instance: MyDatabase
     fun get(context: Context){
          // autoinit or get 
     }

     fun set(db: MyDatabase){
         // set it after sign out
     }
```

One thing you should also be responsible for - is thread-safety to initialize it correctly

Comment: so how exactly would it look like for the aforementioned workflow, in terms of setting and getting the database? the gets are obvious, they are injected anyway. but what about set? do i close the database using the object with `MyDatabaseProvider.set(null)`? how would this differ from the currently implemented code, couldn't i just do the same in the `MyDatabase() : RoomDatabase` class?